# Moo Accordion hides under footer in IE9 when I activate it

Tags: joomla, mootools, joomla-extensions

Moo accordion is going under footer instead of moving footer to downside. I am having this problem in some computers with Windows 7. I am attaching photo. You can visit website here http://oscebmsc.org/en/courses
Please provide with advice how to solve this problem.
In my computer I do not have such problem I am using IE9 and Windows Vista[image], but my contractors having this issue with IE9 and Windows 7.

But when they refresh one more time, problem is removed. But in first load always such a problem.

Comment: i saw it in the rendered html. Now i looked closer and I see you are using jQuery to assign the height of that div on load function in your script.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your on load function `jQuery(window).height();` which doesn't work in IE

replace with

```
$(window).innerHeight();
```

source:

[$(window).height() fails on IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692746/window-height-fails-on-ie9)

Comment: I have changed as you told, they are still having problem

Comment: *change just $(window).innerHeight(); not jQuery("#content").innerHeight();

Comment: I first changed $(window).innerHeight(); nothing worked. Then changed content as well, nothing changed.

Comment: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow
found that off the source page. might be worth a look.

Comment: I think the problem is some where else, maybe it is in mootools plugins?

Comment: your content div is what determines how large that area is. that onload function is what sets it height: 725px; (inline) is what it is set to on chrome. in IE9 its set to less thus your bug. can only be that onload functions but if you would like to debug it just add an alert on the 3 values load page in chrome and then ie see the diff

Comment: The problem is that in my IE9 and Chrome everything works fine. The problem is in the browser of my boss. So I can not test why it is happening. By the way thank you for you help. I will try to search the problem deeper.

Comment: Try including the jQuery library before Mootools in your template index.php file